# Help me identify this houseplant?

Tags: identification

About a month ago I bought this cute little unlabeled plant at the grocery store. I’ve looked up what it could be multiple times but I’ve had no luck in identifying it. I’d love to learn more about it and its needs. Can anyone tell me what it is?[image]